# Hard link cells in script editor for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When in Google Spreadsheet, you have formula's referencing cells to make for example a simple sum, Spreadsheets will automatically update the references, should the cells be moved. For example if the cells where cut and pasted to a different location, or rows/columns where added somewhere.

I've got this Spreadsheet where I refresh some data in using REST API's in the Spreadsheet script editor. This one runs every 5 minutes or so. However if the cells in which the data needs to be inserted, move around, my script breaks. So I have a list of constants with all kinds of cell names, for example:

```
/* --- EXCHANGE RATES --- */
var CELL_BTC_EUR = "B3";
var CELL_ETH_EUR = "B4";
var CELL_BNK_EUR = "B5";
```

But I need to update these every time I move something to optimize the spreadsheet. Is there a way to hard link it to a specific cell so that they automatically update similar to in cell formula's? Maybe not with these constant but with lines like:

```
sheet.getRange(CELL_BTC_EUR).setValue(btceur.last);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Potential solution**

I make a seperate sheet with all my "dynamic" data which is refreshed via Spreadsheet script. In my main sheet, I can reference those cells. Thus if in my mainsheet things start moving, the reference to my other sheet stay the same. I can then hide/protect the Script Sheet.

I'm still gonna make a small table in my mainsheet with my currency exchange rates, just to get an overview of everything. But my references would not break anymore everytime I insert a new coin or something.

(better solutions are welcome. :) )